# How to programmatically format text between start and end tags and then remove the tags

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**Edit: the below endeavor is related to Google Apps Script to format text in a Google Doc.**

I'm not familiar with JavaScript and really have only done some small bit of R coding and so this effort is a bit of parsing what I can google as well as some trial and error. I've had some promising success, but I'm also having some trouble finding a complete answer to the following scenario.

### Context

I have a google doc template that has embedded merge codes. A separate application is pulling data fields from objects and related objects and replacing those merge codes with unformatted text. A side effect of this application is that I cannot format the merge codes ahead of time so that when replaced, the text is formatted appropriately. Therefore I'm trying to create a script to run following text merge to programmatically apply some formatting.

### What I Need

I have three different styles I need to apply. I am creating code to search for start tags and end tags and then format the text between. In a perfect world the tags would also then be removed from the document leaving only the formatted text behind.

| Styled Item | Tags | Formatting to be applied |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Requests | `<req>` `</req>` | Roboto 10, Bold, #4a5356 |
| Citations | `<cit>` `</cit>` | Lato 8, Bold, #4A5356 |
| Conclusions | `<con>` `</con>` | Lato 8, Bold, #B38F00 |

### Code so Far

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Butler')
      .addItem('Format Headings', 'FormatRequests')

      .addToUi();
}

function FormatRequests() {
  var startTag = '<req>';
  var endTag = '</req>'
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  for(var i in para){  
    var from = para[i].findText(startTag);
    var to =  para[i].findText(endTag,from);
    if((to != null && from != null) && ((to.getStartOffset()-1) - (from.getStartOffset()+startTag.length) > 0) ){
      para[i].editAsText().setBold(from.getStartOffset()+startTag.length, to.getStartOffset()-1, true);
    }
  }
}
```

So far I've succeeded in finding the tags and setting text between the tags to bold. But I don't know how to continue to apply the remainder of the formatting or how to remove the tags once the formatting has been applied.

Any ideas?

Comment: And, btw, thank you for your well formatted question. It happens not too often these times. Especially among newcomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function main() {

  handle_tags(['<req>', '</req>'], "Roboto", 10, "Bold", "#4a5356");
  handle_tags(['<cit>', '</cit>'], "Lato", 8, "Bold", "#4a5356");
  handle_tags(['<con>', '</con>'], "Lato", 8, "Bold", "#B38F00");
  
}

function handle_tags(tags, family, size, style, color) {

  var body      = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var start_tag = tags[0];
  var end_tag   = tags[1];
  
  var found     = body.findText(start_tag);

  while (found) {
    var elem    = found.getElement();
    var start   = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    var end     = body.findText(end_tag, found).getStartOffset()-1;

    elem.setFontFamily(start, end, family);
    elem.setFontSize(start, end, size);
    elem.setForegroundColor(start, end, color);

    switch (style.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'bold': elem.setBold(start, end, true); break;
      case 'italic': elem.setItalic(start, end, true); break;
      case 'underline': elem.setUnderline(start, end, true); break;
    }

    found = body.findText(start_tag, found);
  }

  body.replaceText(start_tag, '');
  body.replaceText(end_tag, '');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Yuri! This worked amazingly well and is very easy to interpret!

Answer (score 1):

So, what I've done is converted the data into an array and using that array I've made the desired formatting.

So, if this the data:

```
Hey! <req>My name is John</req> and I am a <cit>web developer</cit> from Canada. I love coding and solving problems. <con>Ping me if you want to talk code</con>.
```

I will convert this into the following nested array, where the first item at every index specifies the start index.

```
[
  [ 0, 'Hey! ' ],
  [ 5, 'My name is John', '<req>' ],
  [ 20, ' and I am a ' ],
  [ 32, 'web developer', '<cit>' ],
  [ 45, ' from Canada. I love coding and solving problems. ' ],
  [ 95, 'Ping me if you want to talk code', '<con>' ],
  [ 127, '.' ]
]
```

NOTE: I've used `~` and `^` characters to split the data, hoping that these two characters don't appear in your data.

**Working Code Below:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  const allText = body.editAsText();
  const arr = splitText(allText.getText())
  
  allText.deleteText(0, allText.getText().length - 1)

  for (let el of arr) {
    let someText = allText.appendText(el[1])
    let start = el[0];
    let end = el[0] + el[1].length - 1;

    if (el.length > 2) {
      if (el[2] === "<req>") {
        someText.setFontFamily(start, end, DocumentApp.FontFamily.ROBOTO);
        someText.setFontSize(start, end, 10);
        someText.setBold(start, end, true);
        someText.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#4a5356")
      }else if(el[2] === "<cit>") {
        someText.setFontFamily(start, end, DocumentApp.FontFamily.TIMES_NEW_ROMAN);
        someText.setFontSize(start, end, 8);
        someText.setBold(start, end, true);
        someText.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#4a5356")
      }else if (el[2] === "<con>") {
        someText.setFontFamily(start, end, DocumentApp.FontFamily.TIMES_NEW_ROMAN);
        someText.setFontSize(start, end, 8);
        someText.setBold(start, end, true);
        someText.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#b38f00")
      }
    } else {
      someText.setFontFamily(start, end, null);
        someText.setFontSize(start, end, null);
        someText.setBold(start, end, null);
        someText.setForegroundColor(start, end, null)
    }
  }
}

function splitText(data) {
  return data
  .replace(/<([a-z]{3})>/g, "~")
  .replace(/<\/([a-z]{3})>/g, "^<$1>~")
  .split("~")
  .map((s) => s.split("^"))
  .reduce((r, s, i, a) => (i === 0? r.push([0, ...s]): r.push([r[i - 1][0] + a[i - 1][0].length, ...s]), r), [])
}
```

Comment: @HaldavidCope Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @Shekar Mukherjee,  will this also work for Google Apps Script? Sorry I did not mention that fact in my post, but I tagged it as Google Apps Script related.

Comment: @HaldavidCope Okay not I got your actual problem, give me some time I'll update my answer.

Comment: @HaldavidCope Please check my updated answer, it is written in google script and I've tested it on google docs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance Shekar! This is very clever, but I think is a little less straightforward than Yuri's response below. Really appreciate your help. Definite applicability from this to other projects!

Comment: @HaldavidCope It was really an interesting question got to learn a lot from it. If your problem is resolved consider accepting some answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  I’ve done so now!”.