# Bold text in between double-star (**) characters like in Markdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Hi I have an issue with google docs. The below code is not working for me.
What I want to achieve is that I have a text which contains key words which are between **. Those double stars are at the beginning and at the end. Based on that I want to make this text bold. After script will stop working I would like to perform next action to remove those ** from document.
Could you help me?

```js
function formatTextAsBold() {
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();
  var textElements = body.getParagraphs().flatMap(function (paragraph) {
    return paragraph.findText("\\*\\*(.*?)\\*\\*").map(function (match) {
      return match.getElement();
    });
  });
  
  textElements.forEach(function (element) {
    var text = element.asText();
    var startIndex = text.getText().indexOf("**");
    var endIndex = text.getText().lastIndexOf("**") + 2;
    
    text.setBold(startIndex, endIndex, true);
    text.deleteText(startIndex, startIndex + 2);
    text.deleteText(endIndex - 2, endIndex);
  });
}
```

In apps critps I received error message

> ReferenceError: javascript is not defined (anonymous) @ Bold text.gs:1

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [How to programmatically format text between start and end tags and then remove the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345950/how-to-programmatically-format-text-between-start-and-end-tags-and-then-remove-t)

```
function formatTextAsBold() {

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var tag = '\\*\\*';
  var found = body.findText(tag);

  while (found) {
    var elem  = found.getElement();
    var start = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    var end   = body.findText(tag, found).getStartOffset()-1;

    elem.setBold(start, end, true);

    found = body.findText(tag, found);
    found = body.findText(tag, found);
  }

  body.replaceText(tag, '');
}
```